# What is the word that actors use to describe the process of getting familiar with a script?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that theatre people use to describe the initial stages of reading through a script. It's something like *chewing the script* or *singing the script*.

Comment: I've never encountered anything like either of these. Do you mean the actor's work before rehearsals start, or the early stages of rehearsal, or what?

Comment: Dunno if there's any specialised Tinseltown terminology, but for the more general case one tends to [***digest** the script*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22digest+the+script%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers And under that alimentary metaphor the performance itself would be ... ?

Comment: @StoneyB: All great actors (along with [Carroll's White Queen](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Quotations/Dodgson.html)) have to be good at believing in unlikely possibilities. So I'm sure they all think that given the right attitude and application, they can [polish a turd](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiJ9fy1qSFI) when it finally appears on the night!

Comment: [Please ‘never’ use   on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Comment: [*Chewing the Scenery*](http://avhstheatre.org/lingo.htm) - *The description of zealous overacting*. It was bugging me your reference to *chewing the script*, I finally found it! But it is quite unrelated to actors learning their lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[study](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/study)*** is a theatre term used in this sense:

> **6.** *v* (tr) to try to memorize: *to study a part<sup>[1](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/part)</sup> for a play.* 
> **15.** *n* (Theatre) *theatre* a person who memorizes a part<sup>[1](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/part)</sup> in the manner specified: *a quick study*
>
> ---
>
> <sub>**1** (Theatre) 
>
> a. an actor's role in a play
>
> b. the speech and actions which make up such a role
>
> c. a written copy of these</sub>

Apparently, it can be applied to both the person and the action that person does.

---

From the book "The Language of Theatre" *edited by Martin Harrison*:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I disagree, to study for a role is something that an individual does,  the actor researches his character (imaginary or real) in depth in order to give a believable performance. Instead, the OP asked for the initial stages in the reading of the script, this is like getting a feel of the story, the plot, how the different characters interact with one another.

Comment: @Mari-Lou-A: In my opinion, "study" covers them all.

Comment: I also support Sven Yargs' answer which covers the initial reading part. But OP also asked the process of getting familiar with it. The whole process is studying.

Comment: @Mari-Lou-A is right with usage.  Plus studying a script is reviewing the nuasances of the play/movie to get in character... not learning their lines.

Comment: @RyeBread: It covers learning the lines of a part. It is even in the source that I gave.

Answer (score 2):

The term I'm familiar with for initial familiarization with a script is **first read-through**—but that's not very zippy. [Wiktionary's glossary of theatre terms](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aGlossary_of_theatre) suggests two other terms that might be relevant:

> **cold reading** A reading from a script or other text without any prior rehearsal, usually in the context of an audition or workshop.

and

> **run Italians** To speak one's lines very fast,  either individually or as a cast; thought to assist in committing lines and cues to memory.

According to Angela Mitchell at [About.com Performing Arts](http://performingarts.about.com/od/Stage_Slang/g/Cold-Reading.htm), a **cold reading** may also be used "as a precursor to the start of the rehearsal process."

Comment: There's also [run-through](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dress_rehearsal#In_a_theatre_or_opera_house) which is akin to a rehearsal, but whose main function is to help actors learn their lines.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: The best new-to-me bit of theater slang I encountered while researching this question was from Improper Arts.com (http://www.improperarts.com/jargon/): "SITZPROBE: The first rehearsal between actors and the orchestra." This may be a regional (southern Alberta) term only, however.

Comment: Also there is **walk-through**, which is an early rehearsal including movements and reading through the script while on the stage.

Comment: I did find this term [chewing the scenery](http://avhstheatre.org/lingo.htm) which links up with the OP's suggestion of "chewing the script".

Answer (score 1):

Actors would **[memorize](https://www.google.com/search?q=actors%20memorizing%20lines&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb#channel=sb&q=actors%20memorizing%20script&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial)** their lines or the script.  I am sure an actor would just say, "I need to *learn* the script."

Also for some actors, especially doing plays, they wouldn't normally memorize everything on their own.  They would **practice** their script (with the others in the performance) or **rehearse** the script.

Answer (score 1):

How about [familiarize/familiarise](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/familiarize)?